# Triangle arrow on left side to the top instead of centered position

Tags: html, css

Is it possible - with this markup - to move the triangle arrow more to the top of this margin, instead of centered position?

```css
#wrapper {
  background: #ccc;
  padding: 20px;
  }
.arrow_box {
 position: relative;
 background: #fff;
 border: 4px solid #fff;
}
.arrow_box:after, .arrow_box:before {
 right: 100%;
 top: 50%;
 border: solid transparent;
 content: " ";
 height: 0;
 width: 0;
 position: absolute;
 pointer-events: none;
}

.arrow_box:after {
 border-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
 border-right-color: #fff;
 border-width: 10px;
 margin-top: -10px;
}
.arrow_box:before {
 border-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
 border-right-color: #fff;
 border-width: 16px;
 margin-top: -16px;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div class="arrow_box">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why are there two triangles?

Comment: I don't see two... should be one...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change the way you `position` your arrow to `absolute` and move it wherever you need.

Like here, based on your example : https://jsfiddle.net/0f44sz8z/

Answer (score 1):

If you change to `margin-top: -30px;` on both `after` and `before` pseudo elements you will achieve that:

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/37sj72v7/)